# apache virtual hosts - server not found for subdomain

Tags: centos, apache-2.2, virtualhost

I want to set up a subdomain using virtual hosts. I have altered the httpd.conf file as follows, but I get a "can't find server" error when I try to access the url. I'm running Centos 5.5.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
#
# NOTE: NameVirtualHost cannot be used without a port specifier
# (e.g. :80) if mod_ssl is being used, due to the nature of the
# SSL protocol.
#

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for requests without a known
# server name.
#
#<VirtualHost *:80>
#    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
#    DocumentRoot /www/docs/dummy-host.example.com
#    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
#    ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
#    CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
#</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.mydomain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/test_mydomain_com/"
    ServerName test.mydomain.com
    ErrorLog logs/test_mydomain_com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/test_mydomain_com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

I have:

- Checked the syntax is valid by "service httpd configtest"
- Restarted Apache
- Checked that the DocumentRoot described above does indeed get to the folder I have my index.php file in for the subdomain.

I'm suprised that even though it can't find the subdomain, it doesn't get routed to the www.mydomain.com area because that's what I thought that I'd set it up to do with the first virtual host statement.

I'm trying to access the subdomain by:

```
http://test.mydomain.com
```

Do I need to do anything to (and thus learn about) the DNS settings to acheive what I want here? Is that what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need either a A record or CNAME record added to your DNS server in order for that to work. Sounds like you do not have one. You can confirm for us by posting `host test.mydomain.com`.

If you get back:

`Host test.mydomain.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`

Then that is your problem.

Either add an A record (hostname -> IP) or a CNAME (hostname -> hostname) for test.mydomain.com and you should be in business.

Comment: Which file do I need to alter to add the A record? I've gone through a chapter on DNS in a book I have on Centos which used bind-chroot but it's got very complicated and I'm not sure I need it all. It has suggested setting up my own DNS server. Do I need to do this? Is there not just a one line A record that I can add somewhere.

Comment: I do not recommend setting up your own DNS server, it far more complicated than is necessary. Presumably someone already hosts your DNS for "mydomain.com"; whoever/whereever that is hosted is where you'll simply want to add (or have them add) a new A or CNAME record. Usually this is as simple as adding one line to the DNS zone file, updating the SOA and reloading the `named` process.

Comment: Great. Yes I did this and it's working now. Many thanks for coming back to me on this. I don't know why I didn't think of doing that. I must play around with this though as I want to understand it all. Main thing is that I can now add domains and subdomains which is great! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting a "Server not found" error, then that's likely a DNS problem, not apache.

Did you create a DNS record for the new subdomain?

Comment: No I didn't. I'll have a go. Thanks for the reply.